# Script that will print HTTP headers for multiple servers

Tags: bash, curl

I've created the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(cat targets.txt); do
"curl -I -k https://"${ip};
"curl -I http://"${ip}
done
```

However I am not receiving the expected output, which is the HTTP header responses from IP addresses listed in targets.txt

I'm not sure how curl can attempt both HTTP and HTTPS (80/443) within one command, so I've set two seperate curl commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nmap` might be more appropriate for the task: `nmap -iL targets.txt -p T:80,443 -sV --script=banner --open`

Perform a network map (`nmap`) of hosts from the input list (`-iL targets.txt`) on TCP ports 80 and 443 (`-p T:80,443`) with service/version detection (`-sV`) and use the banner grabber script (`--script=banner`, ref. https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/banner.html). Return results for open ports (`--open`).

... or `masscan` (ref. https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan): `masscan $(cat targets.txt) -p 80,443 --banners`

Mass scan (`masscan`) all targets on ports 80 and 443 (`-p 80,443`) and grab banners (`--banners`).

Comment: @Jase cool, glad I could help. Maybe consider accepting as the answer? 

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around your curl commands. You also don't need the `;` after the first curl.

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(cat targets.txt); do
  curl -I -k https://${ip}
  curl -I http://${ip}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some `echo`'s to @John's answer to be able to have a better visibility of the results of the `curl` executions. Also added port 8080 in case of proxy.

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(cat $1); do
  echo "> Webserver Port Scan on IP ${ip}."
  echo "Attempting IP ${ip} on port 443..."
  curl -I -k https://${ip}
  echo "Attempting IP ${ip} on port 80..."
  curl -I http://${ip}
  echo "Attempting IP ${ip} on port 8080..."
  curl -I http://${ip}:8080
done
```